# Give an effect to all over the page except an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom-events

I want to put this code on my Page:

```
function addLink() {  
    var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];  
    var selection; selection = window.getSelection();  
    var pagelink = "<br /><br /> original: <a href='"+document.location.href+"'>"+document.location.href+"</a>";  
    var copytext = selection + pagelink;  
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); newdiv.style.position='absolute';  
    newdiv.style.left='-99999px';  
    body_element.appendChild(newdiv);  
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;  
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);  
    window.setTimeout(function() {  
        body_element.removeChild(newdiv);  
    }, 0);
} 
document.oncopy = addLink;
```

But this code action's for all of the tags and I want to don't action in the "textareas".

Comment: I don't get it - what are you trying to achive with this script?

Answer (score 0):

Test `tagName` before `addlink()`

```
document.body.addEventListener('copy', function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'textarea') {
        return;
    }
    addlink()
}
```

Comment: substitute `document.oncopy = addLink;` line in your code with mine.

Comment: Thank you very much . but when i tested the new code , it doesn't work!!